# Unable to discover services on a Bluetooth device

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-service-discovery

I'm writing an application that is able to communicate with my PC. I have used the Bluetooth functionalities of the SDK 2.1.

I can find devices, get their MAC address, create an [RFCOMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols#Radio_frequency_communication_.28RFCOMM.29) socket, but when I start the connection, I get the following error message.

> Service discovery failed.

1. Is it because of the [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), which is not the same on my application and on my PC?
2. How can I get the correct UUID on my PC?

If I write a such application, is my [Nexus One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_One) the client or the server?

Answer (score 7):

OK, I got the same problem, but I think I can answer a few of your questions. If your PC opened an SPP Port, for example, by using "sdptool add --channel=3 SP" your Android phone would be the client opening a socket and connecting with this socket to the server (your PC or any other Bluetooth device, for example, GPS, mouse, etc.).

You can get this information by reading the article *[Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)*, the definition of a client did I take out of this article.

If you are opening an SPP Port on the server (your PC, etc.) you are offering a standard service and there is a special UUID assigned to this service. This would be: `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` if I'm not mistaken.

So I think we should get a qualified answer from an Android developer. Or ask this question on Thursday during the IRC office hours.

Comment: Thanks philDev, the UUID "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" worked for me too, running the BluetoothChat sample app with a PC running a basic terminal emulation.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. However if you are connecting to an Android peer then please generate your own unique UUID.

[The Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID))

Answer (score 2):

Although it could be your UUID, I would also suggest you make sure the Bluetooth MAC is accurate and upper-case.

I would also suggest running `hcidump -X` in a terminal on the Linux box, and see if you can see any two-way traffic between your Linux machine and phone throughout the process.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to be sure that the UUID is found on the device. On the client side, before `device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);` add:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'sdptool records " + device.getAddress() + "'");
process.waitFor();
```

The process is frozen during 20-30 seconds, because Android is fetching services. But after, if the server is in discovery mode (if the server is an Android phone), the connection succeeds every time!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when reconnecting SPP after the first connect.

This is because `rfcomm channel=-1` in `BluetoothService.java`. I added `updateDeviceServiceChannelCache()` to the end of `fetchRemoteUuids()`, and then it worked!

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? You included modified Android sources to your project? Or how did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

This thing happens mostly to HTC. I faced the same problem. If you first connected successfully but fail afterwards, just restart the phone and the service that failed will restart in doing so.